# proof: inverse of lower triangular identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

As you know that is enough negating below of diagonal to inverse of lower triangular identity matrix.

example

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
       -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

basically inverse of A

$$A' = \left(
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

I just need to prove it.

my question is not related any software. it is general linear algebra question. It's not enough to say that "if $A'=$ (inversion of $A$), multiplication $A'$ and $A$ should be $I$ (identity matrix)". we cannot say for all case. I need a general proof.

it's related topic with Gauss Elimination - LU decomposition

thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*cannot say for all case*".

Comment: my friend tried to prove it like "if A′= (inversion of A), multiplication A′ and A should be I (identity matrix)". i just want to say that it is not a actual proof. because we should check for all lower triangular identity matrices

Comment: Your observation only works for so-called "Gauss transforms", which are rank-1 corrections to the identity matrix that turn up in LU decomposition. Golub and Van Loan should have a proof of this.

Comment: yest J. M., you are right. it's related topic with Gauss Elimination - LU decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your statement is correct.  For example,
$$
\pmatrix{
1\\
1&1\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&1&1
}^{-1} = 
\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
1\\
-1&1\\
1&-1&1\\
-1&1&-1&1
\end{array} \right)
$$
However, if only the first column is non-zero, then we can write our matrix in the form
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
1&0\\
x&I_3
}
$$
where $x \in \Bbb R^3$ and $I_3$ is the size $3$ identity matrix.  We then note using block-matrix multiplication that
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0\\
x&I_3
}
\pmatrix{
1&0\\
-x & I_3} = 
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&I_3} = I_4
$$
so that indeed, we can find the inverse by negating whatever is below the diagonal.

Comment: thank you Omnomnomnom.  Actullay I showed my prof exactly same thing like your last equality. However, He didn't accept. Because this answer is not a proof actually.

Comment: with following equality, you just showed us A'.A=I 

$$
\pmatrix{
1&0\\
x&I_3
}
\pmatrix{
1&0\\
-x & I_3} = 
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&I_3} = I_4
$$

thak you anyway

Comment: In what way is this not a proof? If $AA'=I$, then $A'$ is the inverse of $A$.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that you don't know what I mean by "block-matrix multiplication"

Comment: I would be very surprised if you actually "already presented the same thing", and the prof didn't accept it as a proof.  What is *"prove $M1 + M2$"* supposed to mean?  Also, I am saying the reverse: if $AA' = I$, **then** $A' = A^{-1}$.  This is always true for matrices.